# Easy debugging in Kohana by printing variables?

Tags: debugging, kohana

Is there an easy way to echo variables to the page (or some other location) from controllers in Kohana? Using Django in development mode, you can easily add print statements that display to the console. In Kohana, I've had to pass off variables to views, which quickly causes problems.

Edit to specify: Kohana 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your version of Kohana.  For v3.1 you will want to use:

`Debug::vars($myVar)`

You can stick that into a variable or just echo it from your PHP file.

For older versions of Kohana, you will want to use:

`Kohana::debug($myVar)`

Comment: That seems to work fine from a template, but how I can I use it from a controller without adding lots of cruft to pass the output to a template?

Comment: You can print Debug::vars() right from your controller if you want a temporary 'fix'. It's not elegant, but it works. ;)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that works for controllers but doesn't display output for helper functions in controllers (eg `private function ...`), or if there is form submission handling.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into [Kohana Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/biakaveron/debug-toolbar/tree/3.1). Its a very useful module for debugging & profiling. For custom vars you can call `DebugToolbar::add_custom('foo', $foo)` and then analyse its dump in special toolbar.

Comment: According to the dev page, it's only compatible with [Kohanna 2.3.x](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana-debug-toolbar).

Comment: That dev page is very old. Take a module from github with my link

Comment: Great, I think that is one of the tools my team is already considering.

Comment: they are optional, you can disable firephp from KDT config file.

Answer (score 1):

echo `Debug::vars()` in 3.1

in 3.0, you'd use echo `Kohana::debug()`.

Comment: Thanks zombor. I'll ask the same question I did for the other similar answer -- That seems to work fine from a template, but how I can I use it from a controller without adding lots of cruft to pass the output to a view?

Answer (score 1):

Kohana DeveloperBar Module may helps you:

https://github.com/marcelorodrigo/developerbar

Comment: that's awesome! got it running in under 2 mins flat.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be using firebug + [firephp](http://www.firephp.org/). You can add debugging statements which would be visible on the firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Its changed in Kohana *v3.3.0(stable)* you can use the `Debug` class  static methods that extends `Kohana_Debug` here is an example to dump debug a variable:

```
<?php

$days = Date::days(2, 2019);
echo "<pre>";
echo DEBUG::dump($days);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

another method is `DEBUG::vars()` example is below:

```
<?php

$days = Date::days(2, 2019);
echo DEBUG::vars($days);

?>
```

for more information on `Debug` class and other methods on Debugging you can check the directory of Kohana debug file is located in **system/classes/kohana/debug.php** most of the methods have very self explanatory name you can use them as your requirement just like above.

Hope this helps :)...!!